# Check whether a branch will be fetched and allowed to be checked-out

Tags: git

Is there a way to check whether a remote's fetch config will allow a given branch to be fetched and checked-out?

By default, any branch is in scope for fetch and checkout but if you're using "--single-branch" with your clone or you've already made surgical changes to your default fetch refspecs ("git remote set-branches"), then you might be able to force your fetch to bring down the right branch via arguments but a "git checkout" may unconditionally deny the existence of a branch.

It seems like there would *at least* be a plumbing feature that can filter one or more items against that config.

More context: [Why can't Git resolve remote branches when --single-branch is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348731/why-cant-git-resolve-remote-branches-when-single-branch-is-used#55348897)

Answer (score 0):

You can at least check the output of `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` mentioned in your linked question.

- if you see the name of your branch, it will be fetched (and can be checked out)
- if you see '*', chances are it could be fetched (but you would need to `git fetch` to be sure)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking about an existing pattern using the existing Git offering that might provide a one-command solution that avoids me/us having to 1) verify that the refspecs are fully-qualified and 2) having to parse the expressions direct from the config.