# How do I do the equivalent of `git remote set-branches origin --add other-branch` in go-git?

Tags: git, go, go-git

I have a huge repository with extensive commit history. To reduce clone time, I do a single branch option with a depth of 1. This immensely speeds up my cloning time however, it cannot properly resolve remote branches [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348731/why-cant-git-resolve-remote-branches-when-single-branch-is-used). Wondering if I can do the samething in go-git?